# How can I find the length of the longest contiguous sequence of 1's in each row of a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe such as

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1], [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]], index=['A', 'B'])
>>> df = df.add_prefix('q')
>>> df
   q0  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6  q7
A   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
B   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1
```

Where the value 1 appears in various places of each row. I would like to create an additional column `max_length_of_1_appears` whose value in each row is the maximum number of times 1 appears continuously in that row. In the example above, the resulting dataframe should be

```py
>>> df
   q0  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6  q7  max_length_of_1_appears
A   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1                        3
B   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1                        4
```

since in row `A` the longest sequence of 1's is from column `q1` to column `q3`, while in row `B` the longest sequence is from column `q2` to column `q5`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using pandas for this? It seems more suitable for numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the series into a list and then plug it into a function that answers your question.

```
A = df['A'].tolist()
B = df['B'].tolist()

def continuous_ones(arr):
    max_count = 0
    count = 0
    for num in arr:
            if num == 1:
                    count += 1
            else:
                    if count > max_count:
                            max_count = count
                    count = 0
    return max_count

df['max_length_of_1_appears'] = pd.Series([continuous_ones(A), continuous_ones(B)])
```

There is definitely a better way to do this if you have a large dataset, like using the `apply` function. Regardless, this should get the job done if you only have two series to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using numpy, you could do this:

```py
arr = df.to_numpy()

# Add columns of zeros to the left and right.
padded = np.pad(arr, [(0,0), (1,1)], mode='constant')

# Get indices in each row where transitions between 0's and 1's occur.
diffs = np.diff(padded)
rows, wheres = np.where(diffs)

# Compute the length of each patch of 1's.
rows, lengths = rows[::2], np.diff(wheres)[::2]

# Compute the maximal length for each row.
rows, split_at = np.unique(rows, return_index=True)
maxima = np.maximum.reduceat(lengths, split_at)

# Store the computed maxima into a new column of df.
df['max_length_of_1_appears'] = 0
df.loc[rows, 'max_length_of_1_appears'] = maxima
```

There may be pandas equivalents to each of the steps here if you look hard enough.